# Set vertex normal in a stable manner with python

Tags: python, mesh, normals

I wanted to set normals from a script, using this code (in a class method):

```
for face in modelMesh.polygons:
    face.use_smooth = True  # normals have effect only if smooth shading
for i in range(len(self.vertices)):  # set normals here because they seem to be lost in some calulations
    if self.normals[i] is not None:
        modelMesh.vertices[i].normal = Vector(self.normals[i])
for loop in modelMesh.loops:
    loop.normal = Vector(self.normals[loop.vertex_index])
```

however, if this sets the normals to the mesh's vertices, they are reset after using `'modelMesh.update()'` or switching edit mode on and off
(and btw it seems that the loop normals stay `'Vector((0,0,0))'` whatever I try, even `'.normal[:] = Vector((1,0,0))'` and `'.normal[:] = (1,0,0)'`)

is there a way so set vertex normals permanently using python?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by observing two mesh importing add-ons, but I didn't understand how exactly it worked.

What I know is that it can only affect loop normals, not face nor vertex normals (so that won't help you if you have faces with "front" and "back" part swapped)

```
mesh.create_normals_split()

for face in mesh.polygons:
    face.use_smooth = True  # loop normals have effect only if smooth shading ?


# <set normals (mesh.loops[ ? ].normal= ? )>


# create custom data to write normals correctly?
mesh.validate(clean_customdata=False)  # important to not remove loop normals here!
mesh.update()

clnors = array.array('f', [0.0] * (len(mesh.loops) * 3))
mesh.loops.foreach_get("normal", clnors)

mesh.polygons.foreach_set("use_smooth", [True] * len(mesh.polygons))

mesh.normals_split_custom_set(tuple(zip(*(iter(clnors),) * 3)))
mesh.use_auto_smooth = True
mesh.show_edge_sharp = True  # optionnal
```

Comment: What I don't get... the "mesh.loops.foreach_get(..." seems to always return an array of 0.0... whatever the values in "foreach_set(...". Any idea?

Comment: maybe update() -ing the mesh before that?
I mean, your problem is precisely what I avoided with this piece of code
by the way, to cover the 2% chance that you didn't see that, you must set the loop normals in the middle of the code.
Hope it helps...